# Setting up moq and verifying that a method was called

Tags: c#, .net, tdd, moq

Using Microsoft Test Framework and Moq I'm trying to verify if a log4net method was called.

```
    [TestMethod()]
    public void Log_Info_When_Stuff_Is_Done()
    {
        SampleClass sampleObject = new SampleClass(); 

        Mock<log4net.ILog> logMockObject = new Mock<log4net.ILog>();

        sampleObject.Log = logMockObject.Object;

        sampleObject.DoStuffAndLogInfo();

        logMockObject.Verify(moqLog => moqLog.Info("do stuff got called"), Times.AtLeastOnce());

    }
```

I get an exception on Verify call saying that

> Expected invocation on the mock at least once, but was never
>   performed: moqLog => moqLog.Info("do stuff got called") No setups
>   configured. No invocations performed.

What am I doing wrong?

**update** the problem was with a getter for SampleClas.Log property. I was always returning `LogManager.GetLogger(...);` even when the property was already set to a ILogProxy.  I was under impression that the property's get accessor won't be called because I've set up a proxy like so  `sampleObject.Log = logMockObject.Object;`

Comment: Is "do stuff got called" the exact string being passed to .Info?

Comment: What does `sampleObject.DoStuffAndLogInfo()` do?

Comment: Nope. Does the parameter matter? I thought the parameters don't matter as long as you are passing something to it.

Comment: @MichaelLiu  It calls Log.Info where Log is an instance of ILog for log4net

Comment: Yes, the parameter matters. If you just want to test that it was called with any string, use `It.IsAny<string>()` for the parameter.

Answer (score 36):

Right now Moq is verifying that `DoStuffAndLogInfo` calls `Info` with the *exact string* "do stuff got called". If it's actually calling `Info` with a different argument, and you don't care what the actual argument is, use the following instead:

```
logMockObject.Verify(moqLog => moqLog.Info(It.IsAny<string>()), Times.AtLeastOnce());
```

Comment: Makes sense. I made this change but I also had to make another change. Please see my update on the question.

Comment: You created a mock for the log but not for `SampleClass`. If `SampleClass.DoStuffAndLogInfo` accesses `this.Log`, it will still call your `get` accessor for `SampleClass.Log`.

Answer (score 1):

The test is correctly set up.

Check your *sut* to see if `Log.Info` actually gets called inside the `DoStuffAndLogInfo` method.

Comment: I agree with this answer.  To give yourself piece of mind, run your same test with my SampleClass and you'll see that your test succeeds.  `public class SampleClass { public void Log(ILog log) { log.Warn("do stuff got called"); } }`

Comment: @JohnRuiz correct, I've also used such a class - only it's `Info` instead of `Warn`

Comment: Makes sense. I made this change but I also had to make another change. Please see my update on the question.

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't look to be the original poster's problem, but in my case I had a very similar error message. It was due to my `.Verify()` call *before* the actual execution. For example, this is **wrong**:

```
SampleClass sampleObject = new SampleClass(); 
Mock<log4net.ILog> logMockObject = new Mock<log4net.ILog>();
logMockObject.Verify(moqLog => moqLog.Info(It.IsAny<string>()), Times.AtLeastOnce());
sampleObject.Log = logMockObject.Object;

sampleObject.DoStuffAndLogInfo();
```

....but this is **right**:

```
SampleClass sampleObject = new SampleClass(); 
Mock<log4net.ILog> logMockObject = new Mock<log4net.ILog>();
sampleObject.Log = logMockObject.Object;

sampleObject.DoStuffAndLogInfo();

logMockObject.Verify(moqLog => moqLog.Info(It.IsAny<string>()), Times.AtLeastOnce());
```